# How should I solve this error: Thread 1: EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=650 MB, unused=0x0)?

Tags: swift, debugging, xcode11

I am trying to run my app which uses this GitHub project: https://github.com/PaoloCuscela/Cards/wiki/Overview

But when I run my app on my iPhone 6, it crashes and gives me the error in the title.

I've written 28 of these in my `viewDidLoad` function and the app runs fine on the simulator.

```
 let tennisCard = CardHighlight(frame: CGRect(x: 67, y: 3362, width: 250, height: 300))
           tennisCard.title = "Exercise 11"
           tennisCard.itemTitle = "Tennis"
           tennisCard.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 255/255, blue: 79/255, alpha: 1)
           tennisCard.buttonText = "See"
           tennisCard.itemSubtitle = ""
           tennisCard.tintColor = UIColor.black
           tennisCard.textColor = UIColor.black
           tennisCard.icon = UIImage(named: "Tennis")
           let tennisVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TennisCardContent")
                tennisCard.shouldPresent(tennisVC, from: self)
                scrollView.addSubview(tennisCard)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like your app uses to much resources.

First of all, check if your assets have big file sizes, and if that is the case resize them to a lower resolution.

Also loading all of these (mostly hidden below the visible area) views into the scroll view at once is very memory inefficient. Try using a table view or collection view that only loads these views when visible. This could also help you get rid of code duplication

Comment: I am suffering for the same error, but I am using CoreML. Could you please elaborate why this is happening in my app. The works fine on other device except iphone 6

Comment: Machine learning can use gobs of memory, gigabytes.  The iphone6 may just not have as much as you need. iOS apps that use too much memory eventually get shut down -- jetsammed