# What Causing Problem Thread 1: EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=650 MB, unused=0x0)?

Tags: flutter, debugging, dart

Recently I developed an application, on android the application did'nt crash but then I try on iphone 6 my application crashes when opening the list. here the list code:

```
 Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  border: Border.all(
  color: KColors.GREY_PODCAST_L4),
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
  left: 28, bottom: 16, right: 28),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child:PodcastEpisodeDetail(
  podcast.episodes[index]),
),

class PodcastEpisodeDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  final Episode episode;
  PodcastEpisodeDetail(this.episode);
  @override
  _PodcastEpisodeDetailState createState() => _PodcastEpisodeDetailState();
}

class _PodcastEpisodeDetailState extends State<PodcastEpisodeDetail> {
  String image;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      final firebase_storage.Reference storageRef = firebase_storage
          .FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child(widget.episode.episodeImage);
      final String url = (await storageRef.getDownloadURL());
      if (this.mounted) {
        setState(() {
          image = url;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
          child: Container(
            width: 64,
            height: 64,
            child: widget.episode.episodeImage != null &&
                    widget.episode.episodeImage.isNotEmpty &&
                    image != null &&
                    image.isNotEmpty
                ? CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: image,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    placeholder: (context, url) {
                      return Image.asset(
                        Images.PODCAST_SKELETON_HEADPHONE,
                        width: 64,
                        height: 64,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      );
                    },
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                  )
                : Image.asset(
                    Images.PODCAST_SKELETON_HEADPHONE,
                    width: 64,
                    height: 64,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 19),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 204,
                child: Text(
                  widget.episode.episodeTitle,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  softWrap: true,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: Fonts.PODCAST_TITLE,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

When i run in xcode it give me error title :
Thread 1: EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=650 MB, unused=0x0)

So why my iphone 6 can't handle it? while my android can handle the app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I solve this error: Thread 1: EXC\_RESOURCE RESOURCE\_TYPE\_MEMORY (limit=650 MB, unused=0x0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606436/how-should-i-solve-this-error-thread-1-exc-resource-resource-type-memory-limi)

Answer (score 2):

**CachedNetworkImage** has properties **maxHeightDiskCache** and **maxWidthDiskCache**, you can use them to compress the size of the image stored in the cache of your device, thus, minimizing risks of getting app crashed.

**Example**

CachedNetworkImage(

width: width,

height: height - 45,

maxHeightDiskCache: ((height - 45)).round(),
maxWidthDiskCache: (width).round(),

fit: BoxFit.cover,

imageUrl: imageUrl,

placeholder: (_, __) =>
const CustomPlaceHolderWidget(),

errorWidget: (_, __, ___) =>
const CustomPlaceHolderWidget(),
),

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is that the app likely consumes a huge amount of memory. Note that the iPhone 6 is an old device, possibly older compared to the Android device that you're currently testing with. If you're including older devices in your targets, you may want to consider limiting the amount of images displayed at a time. Images usually doesn't consume that much memory, but when there's a lot of images to be displayed, it could be.